# printing array elements as individual arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having issues getting the elements of nested arrays to print individually.  The code below prints each element of the main array, but when i try to get the sub-array elements to print separately I receive:

> credentials[0][1]:  null

Please help me. Below is the code:

```java
package authentication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Authentication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\**masked**\\NetBeansProjects\\authentication\\credentials.txt"));
        String credentials[][] = new String[6][4];
        String person[] = new String[4];
        int i = 0;
        String userName = "";
        String passWord = "";
        Scanner inSS = null;

        //read credentials file
        while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {      
            credentials[i][0] = scnr.nextLine();
            ++i;
        }

        //get user inputs   
        scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run = true;
        int x = 0;

        while (run) {
            System.out.println("**Welcome**");
            System.out.println("1) Login");
            System.out.println("2) Exit");

            int y = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine().trim());

            //iterate attempts
            if (y == 2) {
                System.out.println("Exitting, Good-bye.");
            }

            if (y == 1) {
                ++x;

                //get username and password
                System.out.println("\nEnter username: ");
                userName = scnr.nextLine();

                //generate hash
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(passWord.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (byte b : digest) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                }

                String hPassword = sb.toString();
            }
            else {
                run = false;
                break;
            }

            //notification
            if (x == 3) {
                run =false;
                System.out.println("Attempts exceeded");
            }

            System.out.println("\n" + "credentials[0]: " + credentials[0][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials[1]: " + credentials[1][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials[2]: " + credentials[2][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials[3]: " + credentials[3][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials[4]: " + credentials[4][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials[5]: " + credentials[5][0] + "\n");

            System.out.println("credentials [0][0]: " + credentials[0][0]);
            System.out.println("credentials [0][1]: " + credentials[0][1]);//this is where I need the assistance
        }
    }
}

//End of code
```

Results currently look like this:

> **Welcome**
>
> 1) Login
>
> 2) Exit
>
> 1
>
> Enter username:
>
> bruce.grizzlybear
>
> credentials[0]:
>   griffin.keyes 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet
>   soup"     zookeeper
>
> credentials[1]:
>   rosario.dawson    3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor"     admin
>
> credentials[2]:
>   bernie.gorilla    a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret
>   password" veterinarian
>
> credentials[3]: donald.monkey 17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "M0nk3y
>   business" zookeeper
>
> credentials[4]:
>   jerome.grizzlybear    3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "grizzly1234"       veterinarian
>
> credentials[5]:
>   bruce.grizzlybear 0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "letmein"       admin
>
> credentials [0][0]:
>   griffin.keyes 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet
>   soup"     zookeeper
>
> credentials [0][1]: null

Comment: In read credentials block you're just filling `credentials[i][0]` , why you think `credentials[i][1]` has any data ?

Comment: I only ever see your code put something at index 0 with this `credentials[i][0] = scnr.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently storing Strings not arrays into Credentials, and all at the zeroth element of ith element:

Change this:

```
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {      
            credentials[i][0] = scnr.nextLine();
            ++i;
        }
```

to:

```
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {      
            credentials[i] = scnr.nextLine().split(" ");
            ++i;
        }
```

and you would probably get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. In your code, I only see the array being filled at only one place:

```
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
   credentials[i][0] = scnr.nextLine();
   ++i;
}
```

Now consider below image of your array:

[image: credentials array]

Your `new String[6][4]` looks something like above assuming above code ran through `i = 0 to 5`. If you carefully see above, you are only filling the first index, i.e. `0`, of every primary block, which is shown in the image I added as well. So for sure, when you try to access a secondary index other than `0`, you are getting `null` because thats the default value of `String` when you create the array.

To be concise, you never filled the `credentials[0][1]` or in fact any of the grey colored blocks as depicted in the image.